# How can I get an AVG value in MongoDB from the group it has returned?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Well, I have the following collection in my MongoDB Database:

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "departamento_id": 1,
  "nome": "PRODUTO01",
  "valor": 10.511608123779297
}
```

So, silly me went out and did the following to get the **average** value from the field **valor**, considering **all** documents in the collection:

```
db.produto.aggregate({
  "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "avgValor": {
      "$avg": "$valor"
    }
  }
})
```

This had the following return:

```
{
  "_id": null,
  "avgValor": 50.39681773098588
}
```

The thing is, I need to use the value in the "avgValor" field in another query. So, I created a variable and tried to store the result of the created group inside of it. The thing is, when I type the variable name for the **first** time in the console, it works wonders, but when I do it the **second** time, the MongoDB shell returns nothing. Check it out:

```
> db.produto.aggregate({"$group": {"_id": null, "avgValor": {"$avg": "$valor"}}})
{ "_id" : null, "avgValor" : 50.39681773098588 }
> var docMedia = db.produto.aggregate({"$group": {"_id": null, "avgValor": {"$avg": "$valor"}}})
> docMedia
{ "_id" : null, "avgValor" : 50.39681773098588 }
> docMedia
> docMedia
> docMedia
> docMedia
```

Or if I use the variable **inside a query**, the system returns an error. Check it out:

```
> var docMedia = db.produto.aggregate({"$group": {"_id": null, "avgValor": {"$avg": "$valor"}}})
> db.produto.find({valor: {$lte: docMedia.avgValor}})
Error: error: {
    "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue cannot compare to undefined",
    "code" : 17287
}
```

What could be happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the shell, [`aggregate`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) returns a cursor object, not the result docs themselves. When you evaluate the the cursor object in the shell, the shell iterates over it, exhausting the cursor. That's why when you evaluate it a second time it returns nothing.

Instead, call `toArray()` on the result of `aggregate` to get the results as an array you can more easily consume.

```javascript
var results = db.produto.aggregate({
  "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "avgValor": {
      "$avg": "$valor"
    }
  }
}).toArray();
var avgValor = results[0].avgValor;
```

Or in a case like this where the `$group` on `null` assures there's no more than a single result, you can just call `next()` on the cursor to get the one result doc:

```javascript
var result = db.produto.aggregate({
  "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "avgValor": {
      "$avg": "$valor"
    }
  }
}).next();
var avgValor = result.avgValor;
```

Comment: Awesome! It would take me forever to come to this conclusion. Thank you very much!